# Abrasion on my kitten back

Tags: cats, health, injury

[image: abrasionon the back of a 6mo kitten just notice it help i placed neosporin on it, no money for vet right now help please] just notice this tonight doesn't seem to be in pain eating good and playing with my other cat just find.

Comment: that is not an abrasion it is a cut you need to get this looked at by your vet as soon as possible before it get infected.

Comment: Definitely take the kitten to the vet, that is a serious injury. Maybe a claw got hooked in there during roughhousing or another sharp object in the household slashed it open. It is important to treat this right away, preventing infection also prevents massive vet bills from complications.